# SU binary installed, it runs from ADB, but SuperSU wont accept it

Tags: rooting, root-access, supersu

I installed SuperSU on my dev phone (`ro.debugable=1`). I have the proper su binary (PIE OK) installed in BOTH `/system/xbin` and `/system/bin`. The SuperSU APK is installed in `/system/priv-app`. The APK is the only one on my device (I don't have any other SU apps installed).

When I restart and open SuperSU, it tells me "No SU binary installed, I cant install it etc."

I am running Android 5.1 and using SuperSU 2.27 beta.

Comment: 1) Give us the screenshot of the error. 2) From where did you download SuperSU and the su binary? Link the source. 3) How did you place that APK and su file in your system? Link the instructions if you followed any, else, list them here.

Comment: Its the usual error! Tons of screenshots online! Its what it says when you put it on a unrooted phone. See Question for how I placed them (adb push to various system folders)

Comment: Maybe try the latest stable version (looks like 2.65) -- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1538053

Comment: @MatthewRead Did that, didnt work

Comment: Might be off topic but why installing it to `priv-app` ? Wasn't it being installed to `/system/app/` normally?

Comment: I tried both, by the way, I have installed su already.